# Access request object in admin.py outside the class

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I access `request` object, so that i could load **different** admin views, depending on the user's rank.

Below is the code (`admin.py`) I would like to do it, but don't know how to access current user.

```
class AdvancedPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['post_title', 'body', 'rating']

class SimplePost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['post_title', 'category']

if request.user.is_superuser:
    admin.site.register(Post, AdvancedPost)
else:
    admin.site.register(Post, SimplePost)
```

Thanks

Comment: The reason you can't access the request at that point is that it just doesn't exist yet. Admin classes are not registered per request, but for the entire server process.

Comment: So there is no way of doing it? It just looks cleaner that way, rather than overloading all methods..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a single class and override the individual methods as necessary, for example:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return ['post_title', 'body', 'rating']
        else:
            return ['post_title', 'category']

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display for a list of methods that you can override.

Comment: Thanks, can I apply that to other properties as well? For example, listing filters or search?

Comment: Yes, you can override `ModelAdmin.get_list_filter(request)` and `ModelAdmin.get_search_fields(request)` as well. Check out the link I provided.